# Why am I getting a 404 error for a javascript file that is right where it should be?

Tags: javascript, html, permissions

I have a website that is failing to load properly because required javascript files are not being found.

Firebug is showing me an error that says:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://local_mysite.com/javascript/includes.js"
```

And yet, `includes.js` is right there in the `javascript` directory.

The permissions on the file are `-rwxr-xr-x`, and the javascript directory is `-rwxr-xr-x`. I'm not sure if that's correct, but it seems to indicate they are viewable and executable. This is testing on my local server, an Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP setup. This was working before, but it's been a few months since I've worked with these files, so I don't know what might have changed in the meantime.

The reference in my index.html file looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascript/includes.js"></script>
```

Why can't my index.html find the `includes.js` file?

Comment: What web server are you using on what platform?  It will likely have a configuration for where the root directory is for web files (not usually the root directory of your disk).  Perhaps it is looking at a different root directory than you are expecting.

Comment: Has nothing to do with html or javascript? It's a server-side problem. Please re-post the entire question with the necessary details

Comment: Show your call on html file

Comment: @capslock, I've added the call in my index.html file.

Comment: Can you directly access the file http://local_mysite.com/javascript/includes.js if you put it as url in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Try renaming your javascript directory to something else. You may be having an alias problem within apache.

I am going to guess that you're running into a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) error. Try making your markup reference the file relatively.

Comment: The call is relative.

Comment: Can you load the file directly in your browser?

Comment: No, it says file not found if I try and go directly in the browser. (By the way, I did not downvote this answer.)

Comment: Try renaming the directory structure to something other than javascript. You may be having an alias conflict within apache.

Comment: For debugging you could also drop the javascript file into the same directory as index.html and reference it as <script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="includes.js"></script>
.. maybe strip out the charset setting too, although I doubt that's making any difference.

Comment: The aliasing problem you mentioned in the comment I upvoted was the solution. Ubuntu by default installs a `javascript-common` package that creates a default (and, IMHO completely uncalled for) alias that was blocking my own files. Move that comment into the answer and I'll mark this answer correct.

Comment: Note that the same-origin policy does not apply to `script` tags. It doesn't care where the script file is located.

Answer (score -1):

make sure paths are correct and don't forget it is case-sensitive, also make sure if there is paths inside the includes.js are correct, and it is in the same site.

Comment: I believe I have verified all of these conditions.